# What is the technical reason this _itoa_s fails?

Tags: c, ascii, itoa

I'm trying to convert the digit's 0 to 9 to ASCII using `_itoa_s` and I find myself running into stack corruption errors using MSVC2012.

I thought that the ASCII table only occupied one byte per character, but from the looks of things, one byte isn't enough.

Where is my thinking wrong?

```
for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++)
{
  char ch_digit;
  _itoa_s(digit, &ch_digit, 1, 10); 
}
```

I thought this simple loop should succeed, however it fails.  I'm baffled.

Comment: Null terminators are the bane of my existence in C. Argghghh

Comment: @Oli you should write an answer so that this question is accepted and forgotten (and Tony needs some sleep or coffee :-)

Comment: It's funny that the "secure" version of a C function causes stack corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_itoa_s()` should write out one char AND the terminating `NUL` char. You want it to write into a buffer with length = 1. So either you get the corruption error because of uninitialized `ch_digit`, or `_itoa_s()` is not _s (secure) and shmashes your stack by writing behind that one char.

But why not just calculating the ASCII char for base 10 'by hand' instead of using this non portable, MS specific lumber ?

```
for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++)
{
    char ch_digit = '0' + digit; //'0' == 48 == 0x30
}
```

Comment: Actually, I edited it away. The NULL terminator would cause `_itoa_s()` to do nothing, leaving ch_digit uninitialized (fixed).

Comment: The null-terminator (or better zero-terminator) is the `NUL` character (equal to decimal `0`). There is no "*... NULL char*". `NULL` is a pointer value and something completly different.

Comment: Yes, you'd go with null character, without abbreviation, would you? I'm sorry, if that caused serious confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

`itoa_*` writes a *string*, so there's a null-terminator involved.